# Get index value based on condition in angular 2 template

Tags: html, angular, ngfor

I have a json object(items) and I am iterating through ngFor. I need to assign  index value to variable ***i*** only if it matches the condition item.isRepetable==true 
Is there any way I can assign the index value to variable ***i*** in  *ngFor on condition matches

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of items;let i=item.isRepetable?index:0">
           <li>{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: So the isRepeatable value also exist in the items object I assume?

Comment: Can't you assign these indexes to the objects when you get them in the .map() function ?

Comment: @SaiyaffFarouk nope it will be available only in item..

Comment: So, that's there in the items. so that you get it in item when you assign it.

Answer (score 1):

Create and apply a filter pipe, then you don't need a condition and the index will match.

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of items | isRepeatableFilter;let i=index">
           <li>{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

There is no way to modify the index generated by `*ngFor`